# How can I protect my Linux system from future ramsomware's attack?

Tags: security

In future Linux system may be soft target for attack because Linux popularity increases day by day and there is maximum possibility that Linux is soft target for attackers. 
My question is that,
How can I protect my Linux system?
Which precaution should I use for protect Linux system from future attack?

Comment: The availability of exploits is not necessarily in any way correlated with popularity. We can also speculate that the NSA (or those who control it) would learn from the WannaCry incident that weaponizing exploits was a bad idea in the first place, though that's admittedly very optimistic, and probably does nothing to dissuade organizations outside of democratic control and/or values from following their example so far.

Comment: Billy Gates, is that you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see anything particular about Linux and Unix systems regarding such malware. Non-Microsoft focused answers [like this one](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/121265/47947) can be adopted for other operating systems.

Summary:

- Behave like an educated and conscious computer user.
- Do not hand your devices to others, always keep them with you or safely locked away.
- Encrypt your backups and make sure that nobody else can.
- Keep your installed software up to date on a daily basis. Use kernel live patching if you can, some distributions offer it for free and update your kernel on an hourly basis if there are updates available. Reboot regularly.
- Follow the principles of [least privilege](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_privilege) and [trust no one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trust_no_one_(Internet_security)) as best as you can.